# Using $(this) in Dashcode with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xcode, dashcode

I am using dashcode for probably the second time in my life. Working on to see the limitations of dashboard widgets.

I have a  function being called onclick(). I want to use "$(this)" when it the elements are clicked. I keep getting a generic error "'undefined' is not an object". Once I remove this line:

```
var t = $(this);
```

I do not get the error anymore.

I am having zero luck finding information about JQuery limitations in Dashcode widgets.

Comment: Try loading jQuery in noconflict mode

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I thought of that as well but even using jQuery(this) turned up the same error.

Comment: Have you included jQuery before that code was executed?

Comment: What I've observed:
I have confirmed that jquery is included and works with

    alert($().jquery);

to spit out version number.  To confirm html structure I am trying to query, I did:

        alert($('body').html());

I did some dom manip before and found that the above revealed that 'body' no longer exists. The whole dom changed. Maybe this helps?